# Correct way to loop through 2 Dimensional Char array in C

Tags: arrays, c, char

I am getting varied results when looping through a simple 2 dimensional char array in C.  If I have 6 (six) entries in the array it works as planned.  If I had another element I get strange results.  This is also true if I have just 3 (three) entries, it works fine, if I add another, again strange results.

Is it simple the case that I should not expect the condition in the "for" loop to work and that I should really use "sizeof" to determine the size of the array.

I'm sure that Example 2 below is the right way, I just want to understand what is happening with Example 1 and why I get varied results.

**Example 1 - Varied results**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main(void)
{
    char    band[][SIZE] =
            {
                "Beatles",
                "Stones",
                "Who",
                "JHE",
                "Doors",
                "CCR",
                "Animals"
            };


    int     count = 0;

    for (count = 0; band[count][0] != '\0'; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", band[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2 - Expected results**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 20

int main(void)
{
    char    band[][SIZE] =
            {
                "Beatles",
                "Stones",
                "Who",
                "JHE",
                "Doors",
                "CCR",
                "Animals"
            };


    int     count = 0;
    int     aSize = sizeof(band) / SIZE;

    for (count = 0; count < aSize; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", band[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about what happens when you try to check `band[7][0] != '\0'`... You're out of bounds of the `band` array which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ahhh, got it.  Many thanks.  I had assumed that the 7th entry would be identified as '\0'.